# How to use `any` matcher with parameters to the object

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, matcher, assertj

I am facing a problem with using `assertThat(object.method(new SomeClass(someParam)))` as a result, the comparison is when actually running the test, the matcher is comparing object references not the contents of the object as `equals` method isn't overrided.

I don't want to do the following to solve the problem

- Mock constructor since I want to use the real object where the method is actually called
- `assertThat(object.method(any(SomeClass.class)))` since it loosens the test and the parameter `someParam` is important.

Is there a solution which would do something like the following?

- `assertThat(object.method(any(SomeClass.class, someParam)))` where it will match both object calling it with a specific constructor passing the parameter.

Comment: What `assertThat()` do you mean? The standard assertThat from JUnit Assert class has always TWO paramerers. Why don't you use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Mock constructor since I want to use the real object where the method is actually called

This is the wrong approach.

The better approach is to refactor your production code to use *dependency injection*, *separation of concerns* and other OO principles. Then it is easy to replace `object` with a *mock* and use `verify(object).method(eq(parameter));`

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own matcher, I usually extend mockito's ArgumentMatcher...